# Retornar somente uma objeto de cada vez do http get JSON

Tags: angular

Como que eu faço para ao inves de vim o array de todas as perguntas, vim uma pergunta de cada vez no meu form:
Dado o meu serviço:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Pergunta } from './perguntas/pergunta.model'
import { PerguntasComponent } from './perguntas/perguntas.component'
import { Http} from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import { MEAT_API} from '../app.api'


@Injectable()
export class PerguntasService{

  constructor(private http:Http){}

    perguntas(): Observable<Pergunta[]>{
      return this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/perguntas`)
      .map( response => response.json())

    }
    //retorna uma pergunta só, por id
    perguntasById(id:string):Observable<Pergunta>{
       return this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/perguntas/${id}`)
       .map( response => response.json())

     }

}
```

Aqui eu retorno meu array de perguntas tudo de uma vez:

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let pergunta of perguntas" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <app-pergunta [pergunta]="pergunta"></app-pergunta>
          </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Mas quero que venha uma de cada vez, ai quando eu faço o pergunta. id me retorna udefined

```
<a [routerLink]="['/perguntas',pergunta.id]">

  {{pergunta.id}}
  {{pergunta.titulo}}

</a>

import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { Pergunta } from '../pergunta.model'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pergunta',
  templateUrl: './pergunta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pergunta.component.css']
})
export class PerguntaComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() pergunta:Pergunta
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

  "perguntas":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "titulo":"Qual o seu comportamento em relação aos seus investimentos?",
        "opcoes":  [
          {
            "description":"Preservar meu dinheiro sem correr risco",
          },
          {
            "description": "Ganhar mais dinheiro, assumindo riscos moderados",
          },
          {
            "description": "Ganhar mais dinheiro, assumindo riscos agressivo",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "titulo": "Por quanto tempo você deseja manter os seus investimentos?",
        "opcoes":  [
          {
            "description":"até 1 ano",
          },
          {
            "description": "até 1 a 3 anos",
          },
          {
            "description": "de 1 a 3 anos",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id":"3",
        "titulo": "Quantos % desses investimentos você pode precisar em um ano?",
        "opcoes":  [
          {
            "description":"acima de 75%",
          },
          {
            "description": "de 26% a 74%",
          },
          {
            "description": "até 25%",
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
}
```

Comment: como está a sua configuração de rotas? e sobre o último *snippet* de código, qual arquivo ele é e como você chega nele?

Comment: export const ROUTES: Routes =[
  {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'form', component:FormComponent},
  {path:'perguntas', component:PerguntasComponent},
  {path:'restaurants/:id', component:PerguntaComponent},
]

Comment: @mercador eu estava chamando esse componente que é <app-pergunta>, dentro do meu formulário para aparecer somente a pargunta com id e titulo.

Comment: pode fornecer o código do componente `<app-pergunta>`? Se esse componente tiver um `@Input` sendo do tipo `Pergunta` então era para funcionar.

Comment: vou colocar ele na pergunta que fica melhor visualizar

Comment: certo. Eu não consegui entender como você quer que seja mostrado uma de cada vez. No momento você mostra todas as perguntas passando cada uma dentro do `ngFor` para o componente. Se você quer mostrar uma de cada vez, o que vai controlar qual é mostrada a cada momento?

Comment: então cara, isso que está sendo o meu problema, não sei como fazer para primeiro mostrar a pergunta 1, como suas opcoes a,b,c, depois pergunta 2 com suas opcoes a,b e c.. etc

Comment: bom, o componente que possui a referência de todas as perguntas deve decidir qual pergunta deve ser passada ao componente `<app-pergunta>`. Por exemplo, inicialmente você pode passar a pergunta de índice 0 e, baseado em alguma ação, mudar o índice e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: @MERCADOR ou se eu fizesse meu JSON direrente, tipo vou colocar na pergunta

Comment: @mercador acho que assim fica mais fácil que eu chama tudo de uma vez com as opçoes no componente form

Comment: mas o formato desse json ainda é um array de perguntas. Para mim isso não muda em nada sobre o que deve ser feito.

Comment: Assim, vou chamar as perguntas tudo de uma vez mesmo com as opcoes também